# Send variable to another server and get result with PHP

Tags: php

OK I want to send a PHP variable to another server, this is my code, the php variable is an ip address.

```
 header("Location: http://www.domainname.com/bean/data.php?ip=$ip");
```

Basically the other server will get the ip address and return a variable called Description what i am unclear on is the best way to return the description variable back to the server.

code on data.php page

```
 $ip =$_GET['ip'];
 include("ipology.class.php");
 $ipology = new ipology( array($ip) );
 $out = $ipology->out();
 foreach( $out as $ip ) {
    if( is_array( $ip ) ) {
       $address = implode( ", ", (array) $ip['address'] );
       $descr = implode( ", ", (array) $ip['descr'] );
       echo "$descr";
    }
 }
```

Comment: You won't be using `header()` for this

Comment: search around for curl

Comment: depending on your situation, you need to perform a [server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) or [client](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) side request to the other server. Neither of those happens with `header()`.

Comment: Like that you perform redirect. Check the answers, you must use curl or file_get_contents().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originating server could use (as Phil Cross mentions) file_get_contents or curl:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://www.domainname.com/bean/data.php?ip='.$ip);
print_r( $response );
```

Remote server could use:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['ip'] ) && $_GET['ip'] ) {
  # do description lookup and 'echo' it out:
}
```

Using the header('location: xxx'); function, what you're essentially doing is forcing PHP on the originating server to respond with a 302 redirection header which will send the client to the remote server but there's no 'going back' from the remote server to the originating.

Comment: Hi Thanks,  I added the contents of the data.php page (added to the original post) to the # do somehting here section but it doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

That header will simply redirect the user to that website. You want to use something like [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if your server config allows for remote file access.

If not, look into [cURL](http://php.net/curl)

You can grab the contents from the return of curl and process them that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods:

If the only output of the target page is the description, then you can use

```
$description = file_get_contents("http://target.page?ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```

If not, you can use curl like this:

```
// Create Post Information
$vars = array(
'ip'=>'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
'some_other_info'=>'xxx'
);


// urlencode the information if needed
$urlencoded = http_build_query($vars);

if( function_exists( "curl_init" )) { 
    $CR = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://distantpage');
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $urlencoded );
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);


    $result = curl_exec( $CR );
    $error = curl_error ( $CR );


    // if there's error
    if( !empty( $error )) {
            echo $error;
            return;
    }

    curl_close( $CR );

}

parse_str($result, $output);
echo $output['description'];  // get description
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but i am not sure how i would add the contents of my data.php page in to this? and don't see how you get the echo output

Comment: your data.php need to output something like:

`description=description and stuff...&other_info=other info and other stuff..`

and then you can echo `$output['description']` or `$output['other_info']`

Answer (score 0):

Well if we assume that data.php returns only the description you can use

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.domainname.com/bean/data.php?ip=".$ip);
```

It should do the job, but using CURL is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet uses JSON to return the value, this will allow you to return multiple values in the future if your requirements expand.

I typically use XML in place of JSON, but it seems that it is going out of style :-P

Let me know if this works for you.

```
<?php

$output = file_get_contents("http://www.domainname.com/bean/data.php?ip=$ip");

// This is what would go in data.php
$output = '{ "ip": "127.0.0.1", "description": "localhost" }';

$parsed = json_decode($output);

echo "Description for $parsed->ip is $parsed->description\n";

// var_dump($parsed);
```